# Why this code for colorbar labeling works with Matplotlib 2.2.3 but not with Matplotlib 3.0.1?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable, axes_size

arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, (2, 3, 4))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)   
pax = ax.imshow(arr, vmin=0, vmax=100)

cbar_kws=dict(ticks=(0, 100))
cbar_txt='arb. units'
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(pax, cax=cax, **dict(cbar_kws))
# cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(plot, ax=ax, **dict(cbar_kws))
if cbar_txt is not None:
    only_extremes = 'ticks' in cbar_kws and len(cbar_kws['ticks']) == 2
    if only_extremes:
        cbar.ax.text(
            2.0, 0.5, cbar_txt, fontsize='medium', rotation=90,
            va='center', ha='left')
    else:
        cbar.set_label(cbar_txt)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This works fine for Matplotlib 2.2.3 where I get a text in the middle of the colorbar (on the right):

[image: figure_with_matplotlib_2.2.3_correct_text]

But does not work the same way for Matplotlib 3.0.1, where the text gets rendered at the bottom of the colorbar:

[image: figure_with_matplotlib_3.0.1_correct_text]

Why? Any suggestion for obtaining the same behavior with both versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How**

Using `cbar.ax.text` seems to be a workaround for some other problem. The recommended way to set a label to the colorbar is either via the `colorbar` call itself, or via `cbar.set_label("label")`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, (2, 3))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)   
pax = ax.imshow(arr, vmin=0, vmax=100)

cbar_kws=dict(ticks=(0, 100))
cbar_txt='arb. units'
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(pax, cax=cax, **dict(cbar_kws))
cbar.set_label(cbar_txt, labelpad=-12)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The result is the same in matplotlib 2.2.3 and 3.0.1:

[image]

To have the label distance independent of the length of the colorbar labels you may label the left side of the colorbar and shift the label even more.

```
cbar.set_label(cbar_txt, labelpad=-36)
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_label_position("left")
```

Finally, you may indeed use a text on the axes, but position it in axes coordinates instead of data coordinates,

```
cbar.ax.text(2, 0.5, cbar_txt, fontsize='medium', rotation=90,
             va='center', ha='left', transform=cbar.ax.transAxes)
```

**Why**

As to why `cbar.ax.text` works differently between the versions: The internal units of the colorbar have changed. This shouldn't affect any external application, but makes it easier to apply different locators to colorbars. In fact it has become more consistent. E.g. if the colorbar range is 0 to 100, and you place a text at y=0.5, it'll appear very close to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `cbar.ax.text` allows for a more predictable spacing between the text and the colorbar itself. `cbar.set_label(labelpad=...)` uses absolute units (points), which makes it difficult to choose a value independent of the values displayed in the colorbar (e.g. the 0 - 100 range, and the 0 - 1000000 range would show a different distance between `arb. units` and the colorbar for the same value of `labelpad`, and I would not know how to make this independent of the values range). Do you?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that wasn't clear to me. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the label directly? Edit: didn't see answer below. See for better explanation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable, axes_size

arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, (2, 3, 4))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)   
pax = ax.imshow(arr, vmin=0, vmax=100)
cbar_txt='arb. units'
cbar_kws=dict(ticks=(0, 100))


divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(pax, cax=cax, **dict(cbar_kws))
cbar.set_label(cbar_txt, size = 20)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize = 10)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]